# Transforming property values while setting up binding in RX Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a view model property defined as following in view model in iOS.

```
var isIndividualActivity = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
```

In the view controller, I want to set up below bindings based on the above property.

1. When `isIndividualActivity` property in view model is set to true, hide team `UIView` and show individual `UIView`. When `isIndividualActivity` is set to false, hide individual `UIView` and show team `UIView`. I want to achieve this through binding something like as below.

```
    viewModel.isIndividualActivity
                .bind(to: individualView.rx.isHidden)
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

    viewModel.isIndividualActivity
                .bind(to: teamView.rx.isHidden)
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

How can use the same property and invert the boolean binding while binding to those two `UIView`s?

2. I also want the same property to set the top constraint of a `UIView` as below. I am looking for an option to transform the boolean data to a `CGFloat` number while setting up the binding. How can I achieve this?

   ```
       viewModel.isIndividualActivity
           .bind(to: pointViewTopConstraint.rx.constant)
       .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
   ```

PS: I know that I can use subscribe function on `isIndividualActivity` and do true/false check and set the view's visibility and top constraint. However, I want to know if there is a way to achieve using inverse boolean binding and converting bool to value while binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use map:

```
viewModel.isIndividualActivity
    .map(!)
    .bind(to: individualView.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

viewModel.isIndividualActivity
    .map { isActivity -> CGFloat in
         isActivity ? 40 : 0 //example values
    }
    .bind(to: pointViewTopConstraint.rx.constant)
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Comment: Perfect and very precise to what I asked. Thanks.